# Showing a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth surface

Tags: differential-geometry

A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called a surface if for every point $p \in S$ there is an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and open set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ containing $p$ s.t. $S \cap W$ is homeomorphic.

I want to show that a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth surface.

So to do this I have to show that

1. A homeomorphism $\sigma: U \to S \cap W$ exists
2. $\sigma$ has derivatives of all orders

Let $a$ be a point on the plane and let $p$ and $q$ be two unit vectors parallel to the plane and orthogonal to each other. If $\mathbf{v}$ is any point on the plane then $\mathbf{v-a}$ is parallel to the plane, and so $$\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{a}=u\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{q}$$ for scalars $u,v$. So now we have the surface patch (homeomorphism) $$\sigma(u,v) = \mathbb{a} + u\mathbb{p}+v\mathbb{q}$$
This homeomorphism is smooth because it is a linear function? Is that correct?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @tessellation yay!